# SQL Server get number of rows

Tags: php, sql-server, count

I have a table called `replies` and it has a column named `topic_id`.

What I want to do is count how many rows have the topic_id 1.

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [***].[replies] 
WHERE [***].[topic_id] = '1'
```

But in this case I don't know if this is a valid query. If it is, how can I pull it back into a variable called `$num_rows` in my php code?

Note: *** is actually a prefix I covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
--declare the variable
DECLARE @num_rows INT

--get the total number of rows
SELECT @num_rows = COUNT(*) FROM replies WHERE topic_id = 1

--get a distinct count of rows (if for some reason you need it)
SELECT @num_rows = COUNT(DISTINCT reply_id) FROM replies WHERE topic_id = 1

--return the result set
SELECT @num_rows AS num_rows
```

If you just want to return a column called `num_rows` though, this would be a much more efficient approach:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM replies WHERE topic_id = 1
```

Comment: and then do $num_rows = $row['num_rows']?

Comment: Are you trying to pull this back into php?

Comment: Not all that familiar with PHP, so I'll let someone else answer that for you.

Comment: @JamesJohnson - Wouldn't `COUNT(DISTINCT topic_id)` only return 1 or 0?

Comment: @zimdanen: There's no way to tell what it would return without knowing more about the schema. For the sake of clarity, I changed it to `DISTINCT reply_id` though.

Comment: If it's `distinct topic_id`, and you're searching `where topic_id = 1`, doesn't that require it to be 0 or 1?

Comment: @zimdanen: Changed it to `DISTINCT reply_id` for the sake of clarity.

Comment: The SQL code I used that worked was the last line he posted, and it worked! Thank you very much everyone for the support.